# Is There a Way to Check the Count of Angular Watchers on a Page?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to be able to monitor this count for memory pressure troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: How about using AngularJS Batarang?  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$scope.$$watchers.length
```

Comment: Will that aggregate the watcher count across child scopes?  IOW, can I call this on $rootScope and get an accurate watcher count across the whole page?

Comment: No, it won't. You will need to traverse the scope tree.